# PyQtGraph: last element is not plotted out when setClipToView set to True

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

To reduce time to plot for gui update I set the setClipToView(True), to save CPU time from plotting unnecessary (unseen) part of the graph plot. My code is as follows.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
from PySide.QtCore import QTime
import sys
import numpy as np
import time
from collections import deque

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
grams = deque()
penColor = pg.mkPen(color=(0,0,0),width=2)

pg.setConfigOption('background','w')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground','k')
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
view = pg.GraphicsView()
outerLayout = pg.GraphicsLayout()
outerLayout.layout.setSpacing(0)
view.setCentralItem(outerLayout)
view.show()
l2 = outerLayout.addLayout()

lowerGraph = l2.addPlot(name = "lower")
lowerGraph.showGrid(x=True,y=True)
lowerGraph.setClipToView(True)
lowerCurve = lowerGraph.plot(pen = penColor)

def update(grams):
    x = [item['x'] for item in grams]
    yLower = [item['y'] for item in grams]
    lowerGraph.setXRange(0,x[-1]+20)
    lowerCurve.setData(x=x, y=yLower)
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
i = 0
j = 0.0
while i < 4:
    gram = np.random.uniform(0,51,size=1)
    grams.append({'x':j,'y':gram[0]})
    update(grams)
    i += 1
    j += 1000
    time.sleep(0.1)

lowerCurve.clear()
x = [item['x'] for item in grams]
y = [item['y'] for item in grams]
lowerGraph.setXRange(0,x[-1]+20)
lowerCurve = lowerGraph.plot(x=x,y=y,pen = penColor)

QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

when I commented out setToCliptoView(True) last element of the data is also plotted out, but other way around it discard from plotting it.

I guess it is a bug.
Thank you for your time.
Regards,
Upol

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in PlotDataItem's getData function that shows up when you dynamically update clipped data: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyqtgraph/p1UE-zvSI2g

In the latest development branch, change PlotDataItem.py line 564 from

```
x1 = np.clip(int((range.right()-x[0])/dx)+2*ds , 0, len(x)-1)
```

to

```
x1 = np.clip(int((range.right()-x[0])/dx)+2*ds , 0, len(x))
```